# facebook/php-webdriver headless downloads

Tags: php, webdriver, php-webdriver

There are quite a few posts about facebook/php-webdriver successfully downloading files when non-headless, and the same operation failing when headless. I'm looking for a successful implementation of RemoteWebdriver downloading headlessly for this library (facebook/php-webdriver).

The following article suggests that the library does not yet have the flexibility to set a custom command ("Page.setDownloadBehavior"), which may be what's needed for successful headless downloads. But I have not yet seen an example of a working solution in PHP.

https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/issues/605

Any working solutions out there? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague of mine discovered a beautiful workaround to this shortcoming with Chrome/Chromium browser:

> We banged our heads against the wall for weeks trying to get
>   --headless to work with downloads. Here is specifically what we did:

1. Install Xvfb

   `sudo apt-get install xvfb`
2. Start a screen session
3. Start Xvfb process to provide a virtual display

   `Xvfb :1 -screen 5 1024x768x8 &`
4. Add DISPLAY to the environment in the screen session

   `export DISPLAY=:1.5`
5. Start chromedriver (which will have the DISPLAY in its environment)

   `chromedriver &`

Now any chromium-browser processes started by chromedriver will inherit DISPLAY and will use the Xvfb virtual display.